# Two computer, same code, two results (Insert and update)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I made program, build release and on my computer it works excellent, but when I install it on client computer I get few errors. 
Biggest enigma for me is this code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox6.Text))
        {
            string komanda = "";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            string naziv = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
            string obim = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
            string format = Convert.ToString(textBox4.Text);
            string isbn = Convert.ToString(textBox5.Text);
            decimal cena = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox6.Text);

            if (Izbor.Equals(1))
            {
                komanda = "INSERT INTO Izdanja (Naziv, Obim, Format, ISBN, Cena) VALUES (N'" + naziv + "','" + obim + "','" + format + "','" + isbn + "','" + cena + "')";
            }
            else if (Izbor.Equals(2))
            {
                komanda = "UPDATE Izdanja SET Naziv = N'" + naziv + "', Obim ='" + obim + "', Format ='" + format + "', ISBN ='" + isbn + "', Cena ='" + cena + "' WHERE ID='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            }
            cmd.CommandText = komanda;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ucitavanjeIzdanja();
            Izbor = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fields must be filled!!!", "Warning!!!");
        }
```

And enigma is this: on my computer everything work, on client computer insert work, but update don't. Error is: Error converting data type varchar to numeric. How is this possible? If it is error with connection string - insert wouldn't work, but insert work, and update don't. And if error is in code, how it is working on my computer? Same code...

Comment: Perhaps the database is different between your computer and the client.

Comment: No, same database, correct connection string... :(

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: If `id` is numeric, then the issue is likely to be `textBox1.Text`.  You shouldn't enclose numeric values in single quotes.  Actually, you shouldn't be embedding user-supplied values in query strings anyway.  Use parameters and your problem will probably go away.

Comment: In what way doesn't update work? Nothing happens? You get an error? What is `Izbor` and how is it set to 1 and 2?

Comment: Ok, ID is int, but how then is it work on my machine?

Comment: I get error "Unhandled exception...... Error converting data type varchar to numeric." I don't know how to post image/screenshot...

Comment: what value is the user entering into the textboxes? You aren't carrying out any input validation that I can see. You need to add a `int.TryParse` test to `textBox1.Text` make sure they are entering only numbers.

Comment: If button one is pressed than Izbor is 1, if button 2 is pressed than Izbor is 2. Izbor is choice.

Comment: I have validation for field "Cena". It is only field that can contain only numbers. Cena is Price. And ID is auto-filled.

Comment: set breakpoints and step through your code. validate user inputs and make sure they are what is expected.

Comment: You should try to cast textbox1.text to Int32 value type, so it will match the value type of your columnID type into database. Try with : "' WHERE ID='" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)

Comment: That is problem, everything work on my computer, and on clients computer I am testing it and getting error, so I am sure about values that are entered, but I don't have VS on that comp, so I can't make changes there.

Comment: I am building now "Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)" solution. Will give it a try. Info in about 25-30 minutes.

Comment: Okaý i will wait for your report

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. But next answer did. :) Anyway, thanks for all ideas and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't *know* if this is the problem/correct answer, but it's too long for a comment.

Are the values exactly the same when `INSERT`ing and `UPDATE`ing? If not, this might not be related to the query type after all.

For instance, if `cena = 10`, it would probably all be fine, but if `cena = 10.1m`, then all of a sudden the culture of the current thread matters. It might result in `Cena = '10,1'` on the client pc.

But you really should use parameterized queries as Soner Gönül mentioned.

Comment: YES Sir, this is THE answer. This is so stupid that my account will probably be block on this site. Thank you very much. I am pretty mad on myself for not checking such a minor thing. On my comp 10.1 but on client comp it is 10,1 and that was whole problem. Again, thank you. I am going to be little ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Use parameters

This way you are throwing responsibility for correctness of datatypes on your code not pure luck

## 2 Regional settings

You have different regional settings on your machine vs client machine. Look at 1 and convert data BEFORE sending it to SQL.

To prove it, print SQL string on both machines to some kind of log file and look at it how they look when you run application on both machines. You can even try to run failing version in SSMS to see how it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is correct. C.Evenhuis was quicker. I will definitely listen to your advice.